# How do I control which Canvas layer draws first (JCanvas)

Tags: jquery-plugins, canvas, html5-canvas, jcanvas

In the code below I have two Canvas layers one text and one image, the issue I'm having is controlling which layer draws first. When the page is loaded the text may draw above or blow the image, it seems pretty random. Is there a way I can control this behavior?

My attempt:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
            $("canvas").addLayer({
                method: "drawImage",
                source: '{{ url_for('static', filename='100MV-Floor-Plan.png') }}',
                x: 700, y: 300,
            })

            $("canvas").addLayer({
                    method: "drawText",
                    strokeStyle: "C35817",
                    x:{{ room.xPos }}, y: {{ room.yPos }},
                    text: '{{ room.room_id }}',
                    align: "center",
                    baseline: "middle"
            })

            $("canvas").getLayer(0);
            $("canvas").getLayer(1);
            $("canvas").drawLayers();
        }; 
</script>
<canvas width="1397" height="711"></canvas>
<h1>{{ room.current_user }}</h1> 
<form method=POST>
    Room ID: <input type="text" name="room_id"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Click" class="button">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: this is not a flask or jinja2 question it's javascript.

Comment: @FMR Just thought people might wonder why I was referencing strings like '{{ url_for('static', filename='100MV-Floor-Plan.png') }}' in my code. But I guess your right, tags have been updated.

Comment: update the code to nail the problem which is not flask related, that said some problems can be solved dynamically with server side processing but it's better to first come up with a full javascript solution. You might get back to server side solution if you don't find one pure javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After going back and looking over the jcanvas doc's again I found a solution. By using drawImage()'s "load" call back function I'm able to call drawText() after the image has been loaded.

Updated Code:

```html
 1 {% extends "layout.html" %}
 2 {% block body %}
 3     <script>
 4         window.onload = function(){
 5                 $("canvas").drawImage({
 6                     source: '{{ url_for('static', filename='100MV-Floor-Plan.png') }}',
 7                     x: 700, y: 300,
 8                     load: displayText
 9                 })
10
11                 function displayText() {
12                     $("canvas").drawText({
13                         strokeStyle: "C35817",
14                         x:{{ room.xPos }}, y: {{ room.yPos }},
15                         text: '{{ room.room_id }}',
16                         align: "center",
17                         baseline: "middle"
18                         });
19                 };
20             };
21     </script>
22     <canvas width="1397" height="711"></canvas>
23     <h1>{{ room.current_user }}</h1>
24     <form method=POST>
25         Room ID: <input type="text" name="room_id"/><br />
26         <input type="submit" value="Click" class="button">
27     </form>
28 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: If this solves your issue, would you possibly be able to to mark it as a solution by clicking the check mark next to it?

Comment: Looks like a certain amount of rep points are needed in order to accept your own answers immediately. It says I have 12 more hours to go.